# Can't access private String in Parent class for Java

Tags: java, inheritance, private

When I run my program I get this:

> error: name has private access in Animal

The following are my classes:

Animal class

```
public class Animal 
{
    private String name; 

    public Animal(String name)
    {
         this.name = name ;
         System.out.println("The Animal " + name + " has been created.") ;

    }
    public String getAnimalName()
    {
        return name ;
    }
    public String setAnimalName(String newName)
    {
        return name = newName ;
    }
    public void sleep()
    {
        System.out.println("The Animal" + name + " is asleep.");
    }
    public void noise()
    {
        System.out.println("The Animal " + name + " is making a noise.");
    }

    public String toString()
    {
        return "The Animal " + name ;
    }
    public boolean equals(Animal otherAnimal)
    {
        return (name.equals(otherAnimal.name)) ;
    }


}
```

Bird class

```
public class Bird extends Animal
{
    public Bird (String name)
    {
        super(name);
        System.out.println("A Bird " + name + " has been created.");

    }
    public void makesNoise() 
    {
        System.out.println("The Bird " + name + " is chirping.");
    }
    public String toString() 
    {
        System.out.println("The Bird " + name);
    }
    public boolean equals(Bird otherBird)
    {
        return (name.equals(otherBird.name));
    }

}
```

Dog class

```
public class Dog extends Animal
{
    private String breed ;

    public Dog (String name, String breed)
    {
        super(name);
        this.breed = breed ;
        System.out.println("A Dog " + name + "of breed " + breed 
                           + " has been created.") ;
    }
    public String getDogBreed()
    {
        return breed ;
    }
    public String setDogBreed(String newBreed)
    {
        return breed = newBreed ;
    }   
    public void makeNoise() 
    {
        System.out.println("The  " + name + " is barking.");
    }
    public String toString() 
    {
        System.out.println("The Dog " + name + " of breed " + breed);
    }
    public boolean equals(Dog otherDog)
    {
        return (name.equals(otherDog.name) &&
                breed.equals(otherDog.breed));
    }

}
```

Main class

```
public class AnimalMain 
{
    public static void main(String[] args) 
    {

    Animal animal = new Animal("Oscar");
    Bird bird = new Bird("Tweety");
    Dog dog = new Dog("Inka", "Mutt");

    animal.toString();
    bird.toString();
    dog.toString();

    }

}
```

The first class compiles but the other three don't because it can't access private String from the parent class. Now I know this was to occur but is there a way of making it work where the parent class has one private String named name and only one constructor?

Comment: Use the getter!

Comment: Why do you think it is called `private` ?

Comment: *A subclass **does not** inherit the private members of its parent class* - https://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/java/IandI/subclasses.html

Comment: Maybe you should answer this - why do you **want** to access the field rather than use the existing getter method?

Comment: That's the problem I had, where do I implement the getter?

Answer (score 1):

Can be fixed by adding a public getter in the Animal class (parent)

```
public String getName() {
   return name;
}
```

Comment: But how do I access it in the child classes?

Comment: use the `extend` keyword, public class ChildClass `extends` Animal. It will inherit all the public / default fields and methods from it's parent.

Comment: Or you could just use the getter that has already been defined (`getAnimalName()` returns `name`).

Answer (score 0):

The baseclass Animal has a getter for the private variable "name". Use that function, getAnimalName(), in the subclasses that extend the Animal class wherever you would like to get the name. Like this:

```
public class Animal 
{
    private String name; 

    public Animal(String name)
    {
        this.name = name ;
        System.out.println("The Animal " + name + " has been created.") ;
    }

    ...

    public String getAnimalName()
    {
        return name ;
    }
}


public class Bird extends Animal
{
    public Bird (String name)
    {
        super(name);
        System.out.println("A Bird " + name + " has been created.");

    }

    ...

    public String toString() 
    {
        System.out.println("The Bird " + getAnimalName());
    }

}
```